# Firestore and Vue.js: Data must be an object, but it was: a custom object

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuefire

I've tried to update a document in Firestore using Vue.js, but the following errors occur whenever I try to set a new file in a new document.

```
Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: a custom Object object
```

I've tried to set the new field with the `merge` option. In addition, I've also inspected other questions like that on Stackoverflow, but no solution worked for me.

Code:

```js
const ref = this.$fireStore.collection('myDocs').doc(id);
const doc = await ref.get();
if (!doc.exists) {
  return;
}

await ref.set({ test: true }, { merge: true });
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yeah, it was an actual issue in my Nuxt.js code. I used this code in the `asyncData` method which was not appropriated.